# Transforming the difference of cubes into a product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I want to know what happened at the denominator at line 2... Why did it it become like that, going from $x^3 - y^3$ to $(x-y)(x^2 +xy + y^2)$?

[image: algebra]

Comment: Try multiplying out and simplifying $(x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$. Let us know what you get.

Comment: That is a well-known factorization of $x^3-y^3$ — look up "difference of two cubes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes from the identity

$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$.

To see why it is true, simply expand the right hand side. All the terms except the ones containing $x^n$ and $y^n$ will cancel.